# MySQL and PHP Update

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently doing a project for my class project. I'm currently trying to update into the database but I get some errors along the way basically it's a radio button to setup to link to a update page. Any help and insights would be appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>asdf</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Background.css">
</head>
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["login"]))
header("location:admin.php");
?>

<body>
<h1 style="color:white"><u><center></center></u></h1>
<div id="BG"></div>

<form action = "update1.php" method = "GET">
    <table border = 0>
    <tr>
        <td>Image: <input type = "text" name = "image" id = "image"></td>
            <br/>
        <td>Hero Name: <input type = "text" name = "heroes" id = "heroes"></td>
            <br/>
        <td>Role: <input type = "text" name = "roles" id = "roles"></td>
            <br/>
        <td>Attribute: <input type = "text" name = "attribute" id = "attribute"></td>
            <br/>
        <td>Description: <input type = "text" name = "description" id = "description"></td>
            <br/>
        <td>General: <input type = "text" name = "general" id = "general"></td>
            <br/>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </br>
    <input type = "submit" name="update" value = "Update">
</form>
</center>
</html>



<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);     error_reporting(E_ALL);
define("DB_USER","*****");
define("DB_PASSWORD","****");
define("DB_HOST","*****");
define("DB_NAME","*****");

$dbc=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
if(isset($_GET['update']))
{

    $image = $_GET['image'];
    $heroes = $_GET['heroes'];
    $roles = $_GET['roles'];
    $attribute = $_GET['attribute'];
    $description = $_GET['description'];
    $general = $_GET['general'];
    $sql = "update `Dota 2 select` set (`image` = '$image',`heroes` = '$heroes') WHERE (heroes= '$heroes', image = '$image')";
    //  $sql = "Update `Dota 2 select` SET (`image`= [$image]) = WHERE `image`)";

 // $sql = "Update `Dota 2 select` SET (`image`= [$image],`heroes` =[$heroes],`roles` =[$roles],`attribute`=[$attribute],`description`=[$description],`general`=[$general]) = WHERE `heroes`='$heroes')";
 // $sql = "Update `Dota 2 select` SET (`image`= [$image],`heroes`,`roles`,`attribute`,`description`,`general`) = WHERE (`image`,`heroes`,`roles`,`attribute`,`description`,`general`) =     ('$image','$heroes','$roles','$attribute','$description','$general')";

         if(!mysqli_query($dbc, $sql))
        {
echo(mysqli_error($dbc));
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Data successfully updated!';
        } 
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }


?>
```

This is the error for this page 
"
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`image` = 'a',`heroes` = 'a') WHERE (heroes= 'a', image = 'a')' at line 1

"

Comment: `A` != `a` here. and your update syntax is invalid.

Comment: Table names cannot have spaces in their names.

Comment: @Rahi *"Table names cannot have spaces in their names"* - Oh, and why not? They've escaped the table name.

Comment: Oh boy I accidentally gave the unsaved code I'm sorry guys

Comment: The syntax of your where statement is not valid. If you are trying to update only when both of those variables are equal to specific values you have to use AND between them (WHERE (heroes= '$heroes' AND image = '$image') for example).

Comment: @Fred-ii- spaces part is correct that's mistake on my end. However, query has issues which I believe is the parenthesis after SET.

Comment: and I am *blah blah blah* of here. - blah = out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are getting MySQL insert and update syntax mixed..

```
UPDATE `table` set `col1`='val1',  `col2`='val2',....
```

which when set as a PHP var might look like

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `table` set `col1`=\''. $val1.'\',  `col2`=\''.$val2.'\',....
```

More than one way to do that, but this is my preferred way. backticks around column names, and escaped apostrophes around values, since I use single quote strings here

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work  $sql="Update Dota 2 select SET image='$image' WHERE image = ".$image;

Answer (score 0):

The table name has invalid space !

You can set your instruction as :

**"update Dota_2_select set image = $image , heroes = $heroes where heroes= $heroes, image = $image";**

Removing the spaces between table name and using " instead of ' because you can call de php variables $ directly .

Answer (score 0):

Your first `where` is wrong:

```
 WHERE (heroes= '$heroes', image = '$image')";
```

It should be

```
 WHERE (heroes= '$heroes' AND image = '$image')";
                         ^^^^
```

You are also vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Your second one fails because you test for the existence of your `$_GET` value **AFTER** you already tried using it:

```
if (isset($_GET['Heroes'])) {
    $Heroes = $_GET['heroes'];
    ...
}
```